# Embed framework in framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6

Assume I have two frameworks A and B, both required by framework C.

Framework C will be shipped so that third parties can use it in their applications (X).
The problem is, that C just links with A and B and doesn't embed them, which is why X needs to link to A and B as well in order for C to work.

Is there any way to have C embed A and B so that X doesn't need to link to them?

An ideal solution to me would be that the developer of application X would only link against framework C, import the corresponding header and be done with it. Given that C handles A and B, the developer wouldn't need to know anything about A and B.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create an Umbrella framework in iOS sdk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27484997/how-to-create-an-umbrella-framework-in-ios-sdk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; it's possible (at least with OSX Frameworks, so I assume with iOS Frameworks too).

Read the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/FrameworkAnatomy.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002253-BAJEJJAB) about *Umbrella Frameworks*:

> **The Umbrella Framework Bundle**
>
> Physically, umbrella frameworks have a
>   similar structure to standard frameworks. One significant difference
>   is the addition of a `Frameworks` directory to contain the subframeworks
>   that make up the umbrella framework.

Comment: Umbrealla framework, exactly the term I was looking for. Thanks a lot Droppy! Now I'm finally able find some information about this, i.e.:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365578/why-are-umbrella-frameworks-discouraged

Comment: Here is how we can create umbrella framework in iOS http://stackoverflow.com/a/27638841/1582217