# Embedding a framework within a framework (iOS 8+)

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, dynamic, frameworks

iOS applications built with Xcode 6 or higher allow embedding dynamic iOS frameworks within them. I am building a shared framework and would like to embed a sub-framework. How can I accomplish this?

**Note**: This *is* possible and *is* being used in production (for e.g., with Swift frameworks in [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org)).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found the answer. Here's how it's done:

- Navigate to **Target** > **Build Phases**
- Click the small "+" icon and select "New Run Script Build Phase"
- Paste the following:

  ```
  cd $BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR

  mkdir $PROJECT_NAME.framework/Frameworks &>/dev/null

  for framework in *.framework; do
      if [ $framework != $PROJECT_NAME.framework ]; then
          cp -r $framework $PROJECT_NAME.framework/Frameworks/ &>/dev/null
      fi
  done
  ```

Comment: This does work, but just to add that a framework which embeds sub-frameworks is known as an "umbrella framework" and is discouraged by Apple. See this question for an excellent answer of why this is the case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365578/why-are-umbrella-frameworks-discouraged What you should be doing: instead of embedding sub-frameworks, you should preferably just distribute your framework along with its dependencies separately.

Comment: @JonathanEllis This is not always ideal. For example I've added WebP support using WebP.framework. I don't want my main app, photo editing extension and iMessage extension to all have to include a separate copy of WebP.framework. Wastes space...

Comment: @jjxtra If you're building WebP as a static framework, then yes you're wasting space by linking it 3 times. But you should not be building it as a static framework for you use-case. Dynamic frameworks need only be included once and all the other consumers link and resolve the library at run-time. You don't need an umbrella framework to get this behavior - indeed Apple discourages it.

Answer (score 7):

@Vatsal Manot's answer was very helpful for me.  I modified it a bit and also had a need to sign the copied embedded framework.  My script is below.

```
cd $BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$PRODUCT_NAME.app/Frameworks/Custom.framework/Frameworks
for framework in *.framework; do
    mv $framework $BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$PRODUCT_NAME.app/Frameworks/
    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign "iPhone Developer" --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements --timestamp=none $BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$PRODUCT_NAME.app/Frameworks/$framework
done
```

Answer (score 2):

To create a Umbrella Framework that contains a Sub-Framework you can follow the step-by-step guide written down here: [Umbrella framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41397746/umbrella-framework/41815368#41815368)