# Framework Library not loaded: 'Image not found'

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, cocoapods

I have a framework that have Pods and my main project too.

Error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
  Referenced from: /Users/station7/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/472E34A1-3D59-4C1F-90A3-3F3FF2998CC4/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/5E4E1D98-6451-4F1D-8E90-A032029D634D/MyApp.app/Frameworks/requestMyApp.framework/requestMyApp
  Reason: image not found
```

- `Alamofire.framework` exist in framework pods But no in the main project.

> If the framework exist in the `main project` the error never appear. But is in-necessary have `Alamofire` in both projects in podfile, Considering that the main project does not use at all the `Alamofire`.

i'm following this post: [source 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24993752/os-x-framework-library-not-loaded-image-not-found) and [source 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24333981/ios-app-with-framework-crashed-on-device-dyld-library-not-loaded-xcode-6-beta)

**I'm trying all of steps that are sources but nothing works.**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Framework` uses post but put it into the `Main Project`, seems also need `Alamofire` in pods. That is, to fix must be `Alamofire` in both projects.

Comment: Is this the only one solution? since I don't want to include the Alamofire in my Main project.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it was the only thing that worked for me. If you find another way, do not hesitate to comment me, please.

Comment: It is umbrella framework. found solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41397746/umbrella-framework/41815368#41815368 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27868259/embedding-a-framework-within-a-framework-ios-8, but umbrella framework is discouraged by App: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365578/why-are-umbrella-frameworks-discouraged