# Framework with embedded frameworks

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks

I am building private framework `CustomSDK.framework` that uses embedded frameworks inside like `PKHUD.framework`. The issue is that client app that uses my `framework` doesn't see `frameworks` that are embedded in my framework such as

```
CustomSDK.framework -> PKHUD.framework
```

It gives error  `Missing required module 'PKHUD'`
How can I fix it?
Thanks

Comment: Same problem here, did you solve it?

Comment: @user1102026 had to add the src code of the dependent framework to the parent framework.

Comment: @user1102026 also take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48487888/1851930

Comment: do you mean adding source files to the project or just linking the compiled code in some way?

Comment: @Silvia the first

Comment: Thanks a lot! Not desirable but straight and fast solution..and maybe the only alternative unfortunately