# Can I hide embedded module?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm new to iOS Programming.

I want to make 'A' and 'A2' framework and give it to distribute to use every iOS application developer.

Both 'A' and 'A2' uses 'B' Framework, and 'B' uses 'C' Framework. **But I want to hide embedded frameworks('B' and 'C') from developers who use my framework** so that anyone won't have to know about it.

can embedded Swift "module" be hidden like internal classes or structs?

Thank you in advance.

---

This is not a question about creating "embedded frameworks" in Xcode. I just don't want anyone to import my embedded frameworks ('B', 'C') directly

```
import A // OK
import B <- problem
import C <- problem
...
override viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let A = A.default // OK

    A.someAPI() // OK

    B.someAPI() <- problem
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embedding a framework within a framework (iOS 8+)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27868259/embedding-a-framework-within-a-framework-ios-8)

Comment: It is not intuitive with Xcode and the link given by @PGDev is solving it.

Comment: I already know how to embed frameworks :( The problem is I can 'import B' or even 'import C' in the source code which includes 'A' Framework.