# Multiple frameworks and common library

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, cocoapods, ios-frameworks

Using `iOS 8, Xcode 6`.

Let's say I have 2 dynamic frameworks, `frameworkA` and `frameworkB` and they are both dependent on `libC`. In addition, I have an app that uses both `frameworkA` and `frameworkB`. My original thought was to make `frameworkA` and `frameworkB` umbrella frameworks and `libC` a subframework. However, Apple advises against umbrella framework and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365578/why-are-umbrella-frameworks-discouraged?rq=1) describes why umbrella framework is a bad idea due to potential linker conflict issue.

My second option is to use cocoapods (still new to this so a bit fuzzy on details) to use `libC` as a pod which then gets compiled into `frameworkA` and `frameworkB`. However, it occurred to me that both frameworks still has its own copy of the `libC`. Since the app uses both frameworks, will this result in a linker conflict issue as well? Is there a better way to solve this problem?

**UPDATE**
@Rob The projects I work on do require complex dependency management but I kept the problem domain simple in the question to try to better understand how and if using cocoapods can help solve the linker conflict issue with umbrella frameworks. I work with a team of developers who write libraries and can depend on each other's base libraries that provide versioned common APIs. We are required to package and deliver as few libraries as possible to a different organization that is building an app with our libraries and one of their key requirement is that we deliver a dynamic framework.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The best way to solve most problems is to put all the code in a project and compile it. When you have specialized problems that make that problematic, then you should look at other solutions, such as static libraries, and finally frameworks.

Static libraries can make sense if you have a code base that has pieces which require different build requirements. If all the pieces have the same build settings, then just "add files" them into your project from a "common" directory and build your project. Static libraries can be attractive if your build times are very significant and some pieces never change and you want to be able to "clean" without rebuilding those parts. But wait until you start having that problem before you go making complicated multi-package projects.

If you sell closed-source libraries, then frameworks are very attractive. You should strongly avoid adding third-party dependencies for the reasons you note. If you must, the best way is to help your customers package all the pieces as frameworks and have them link everything at the end. But that adds a lot of annoyance; so make sure you *really* need that third-party piece.

You might also consider frameworks if you have a very large piece of reusable code that has its own lifecycle separate from the main products. But again, keep it simple. Avoid third party stuff inside of it, and if you must have third party stuff, then have the consumers link it at the end.

(This isn't a new solution, BTW. When you use curl, if you want SSL, you need to also download and build OpenSSL and link them together yourself. Curl doesn't come with OpenSSL built in.)

But in the vast majority of cases, this is all overkill. Don't jump to frameworks. Don't jump to libraries. Just put all the code in the project and compile it. 90% of your problems will evaporate. iOS projects in particular just aren't that big usually. What problem is a framework solving?

If you have a lot of code that your organization uses repeatedly in lots of products, then I have heard many teams have good luck using internal CocoaPods to manage that. But that's just to simplify checking the code out. It still all goes into a project and you compile it together into one binary; no frameworks needed. Dynamic frameworks are a nice feature in for certain kinds of problems that were really painful before. But, for most situations, they're just complexity looking for a problem.

(If you have one of those specialized problems, edit your question and I'm happy to discuss further how you might approach it.)

---

EDIT: (You fall into that "specialized problem," so let's talk about it. I did, too, for many years inside of a large multi-team Mac and iOS dev environment. And we tried just about every different solution, including Frameworks. They're only new on iOS.)

Within an org like you describe, I would strongly recommend packaging each dependency as its own framework (AFNetworking, JSONKit, etc) and each of your pieces as a framework, and then have the app devs link all of them together at the end. In this way, it is identical to other dynamic libraries (libcurl, openssl, etc.) which require the app dev to link everything together.

In no case should dynamic frameworks include other frameworks that could otherwise be required (i.e. frameworks should never package "third party" stuff). That will explode. You cannot make that not explode. You'll either have bloat, build conflicts, or runtime conflicts. It's like merge conflicts. There's a point at which a developer has to make a choice. App-level linking is making that choice.

Making components over-dependent on other components is the source of decades of trouble, from Windows DLL Hell to iOS apps with competing crash handlers. All the best component systems look like Legos, where the end user assembles small pieces that have minimal dependencies. As much as possible, make your internal frameworks rely on nothing but Cocoa. This has some tangible design influences:

- Avoid directly requiring logging or analytic engines. Provide a delegate interface that can be adapted to the engines of the caller.
- Avoid trivial categories (methods that save just a few lines of code). Just write the code directly.
- Avoid adding framework dependencies that aren't buying you a lot. Don't add `AFNetworking` just to save a few lines of code over `NSURLConnection`. Of course if you're heavily relying on the features of another framework, that's different. But as a framework developer your threshold should be quite high before requiring another framework.
- Strongly avoid being clever in the build or version control. I've seen too many cases where people want to make everything "automatic" for the app-level developer, and so make the system really complicated. Just say "you need to link this and import this and put this in your app delegate startup." Don't create complicated build and version control systems to save 2 minutes on the first build or two lines of initialization logic. These things blow up and waste hours to work around. Don't get clever with `+load` magic. Just make it clear and consistent.

And of course, good luck. Supporting other devs is always an interesting challenge.

Comment: updated. yes, you're one of those special cases I discussed. :D

Comment: Also, do you know if using cocoapods as described would address the linker conflict issue?

Comment: It does, but mostly by avoiding frameworks (I believe CP is now investigating frameworks, but that would bring the problem back). In  typical CP setup, it works out all the dependencies, fetches them, then compiles it all together. That's the same thing I'm recommending, just slightly more automatic (with the trade-off of dealing with a more complicate CP workspace). CP can make it trickier to ensure reproducible builds, though, since it encourages you to fetch "latest" rather than some specific version. After fetching things, you should check them into version control.

Comment: Personally I don't use CP very often. Most of my experience with it comes from talking with consulting teams I know who use it for maintaining their internal shared code like you're discussing.

Comment: Well, delivering each library as a framework is a no-go per internal customer requirements. CP does allow me to specify specific versions and I will still be delivering multiple frameworks, just not multiple umbrella frameworks. Let me know if you know of more issues.