# Missing required module when importing a framework that includes a nested internal framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, frameworks

I have two Xcode 11.3.1 projects for iOS 13.2:

- **MyFramework**: for generating a framework from Swift and Objective-C source files of mine. This source code uses **OpenSSL** framework, which is embedded in MyFramework using "Embed & Sign" option, so MyFramework is a framework that has a nested framework (OpenSSL).
- **TestApp**: a swift application that imports MyFramework (and doesn't need OpenSSL functionality).

When I compile MyFramework, the following directory is created in MyFramework Products directory (Xcode correctly includes OpenSSL submodule inside MyFramework):

`MyFramework.framework/Frameworks/OpenSSL.framework`

Curiously, `Modules` and `Headers` directories are missing in "OpenSSL.framework" (have not been copied from the original OpenSSL.framework), but this seems good to me because I don't want to use OpenSSL functionality directly in my TestApp.

However, when I add MyFramework to TestApp and try to compile it, I get the error "Missing required module 'OpenSSL'" in the swift file where the line "import MyFramework" is. This means MyFramework has been correcty found but OpenSSL hasn't.

If I manually add the file `MyFramework.framework/Frameworks/OpenSSL.framework/Modules/module.modulemap` with the following content (no headers, no exports), then the problem is gone:

`framework module OpenSSL {}`

Is there a better solution? Why are "Modules" and "Headers" directories not copied? Why is OpenSSL needed in TestApp at *compilation* time?

**Additional note (06-09-2020):**
I forgot to mention an important detail. TestApp is able to find OpenSSL framework because I manually added the following path to "Framework Search Paths" in TestApp build setings:
`$(PROJECT_DIR)/Frameworks/MyFramework.framework/Frameworks`

This puzzles me. If a framework has nested frameworks, why are they not included automatically in searching paths?

I found these questions related to umbrella frameworks in iOS:

- [Signing embedded framework not working in Xcode 11.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58822981/signing-embedded-framework-not-working-in-xcode-11-2-1)
- [iOS 8+ framework with nested embedded framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772004/ios-8-framework-with-nested-embedded-framework)

Could MyFramework be considered an umbrella framework and Xcode is not fully prepared for such cases?

Comment: I am experiencing this exact same issue.

Comment: Hi, any updates on this? Have you find another way to accomplish this or?