# pod inside framework project

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I am trying to create some cocoatouch framework project.

since i need some framework like Canvas, afnetwork, and others i install it via cocoapod.

it working fine on the simulator, but when i try to run it on my device it gets this error.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Canvas.framework/Canvas
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/CB1D11AD-0406-43D9-849F-D5C6DFFD3F0C/frameworkTester.app/Frameworks/awsome.framework/awsome
  Reason: image not found
```

i've try to copy manually, and get this error

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Canvas.framework/Canvas
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/EE6C9F39-32B7-4F37-A551-4CD879835ADE/frameworkTester.app/Frameworks/awsome.framework/awsome
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/EE6C9F39-32B7-4F37-A551-4CD879835ADE/frameworkTester.app/Frameworks/awsome.framework/Frameworks/Canvas.framework/Canvas: mmap() error 1 at address=0x011EF000, size=0x00014000 segment=__TEXT in Segment::map() mapping /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/EE6C9F39-32B7-4F37-A551-4CD879835ADE/frameworkTester.app/Frameworks/awsome.framework/Frameworks/Canvas.framework/Canvas
    /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/EE6C9F39-32B7-4F37-A551-4CD879835ADE/frameworkTester.app/Frameworks/awsome.framework/Frameworks/Canvas.framework/Canvas: mmap() error 1 at address=0x0122B000, size=0x00014000 segment=__TEXT in Segment::map() mapping /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/EE6C9F39-32B7-4F37-A551-4CD879835ADE/frameworkTester.app/Frameworks/awsome.framework/Frameworks/Canvas.framework/Canvas
```

using pod version 0.39.0.rc.1, and swift xcode Version 7.0.1 (7A1001)

Comment: see this link may be helpes you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24333981/ios-app-with-framework-crashed-on-device-dyld-library-not-loaded-xcode-6-beta

Comment: nope, i believe that's different problem.

Comment: i dont know excatly , i give some suggestion,

Comment: the app read my framework (awsome.framework) but didn't get the Canvas .framework.

Comment: Well, what am i trying to make is umbrella frameworks, and not [recommended](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365578/why-are-umbrella-frameworks-discouraged).

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: @Nativ yep, make the pod that you use in your framework as a dependency on your podspec, and mention it on your Podfile

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the pods framework is set to required and not optional.
In the target's General tab, there is an Embedded Binaries field, make sure that you add framework there.
If those steps were taken please check this link[Failure on device](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3661)

solution [3744](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/3744)