# Expose Classes of Dependencies in Swift Framework

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I have built two frameworks in swift, let's call them `CoreFramework` and `MyFramework`

`MyFramework` has a dependency to `CoreFramework` and uses some of `CoreFramework`'s classes, structs and enums in its public methods, like this for example:

```
public func fetchData() -> CoreStruct
```

I have set up a podspec for both Frameworks and I can use `MyFramework` as a pod in my project. In my project I would write something like:

```
let result = fetchData()
```

This compiles and Xcode even gives me the right type when I alt+click the variable, but if I want to explicitly specify the type of `result` like this:

```
let result: CoreStruct = fetchData()
```

I get a compiler error and I have to import `CoreFramework`

What do I have to do, to be able to explicitly use things like `CoreStruct` in my project, without having to import the underlying framework?

Comment: I don't know how cocoapod works, but without it, you usually use the 'import' instruction for frameworks as with core dara, foundation and so on. Can you omit this with Cocoapods ?

Comment: But even if I would import lets say `CoreData` would i be able to use things like `NSManagedObject` without additional imports in project? I guess not

Comment: not in project scope, you're right. Except if you do it in the main file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way in Swift to make importing one module automatically import another. That was a conscious choice on the language designers’ part, and Swift is strict about it.

There is something called an “umbrella framework” which *sort of* does what you want by letting you create a facade for several subframeworks, but Apple [specifically discourages you from creating one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365578/why-are-umbrella-frameworks-discouraged).

Barring that, you must ensure that (in your example) `fetchData()` and `CoreStruct` are compiled into the same framework, which you could do by:

- having `MyFramework` include `CoreFramework`’s code as a git submodule,
- having `MyFramework` use Cocoapods to build `CoreFramework` within the same workspace (i.e. publish `CoreFramework` as a pod, and include it in `MyFramework` *without* the `use_frameworks` option in the podfile, so that you get two projects in one workspace compiled into one framework),
- merging the projects (i.e. just add all the source files from `MyFramework` and `CoreFramework` to the same project),

…or anything else that causes the two source trees to be compiled into one framework.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you elaborate on the 
"having MyFramework use Cocoapods to build CoreFramework into the same workspace" part?

Comment: See edits. It’s basically just a fancy way of merging the codebases, only useful if you have reason to publish/use CoreFramework independently of MyFramework.

Comment: Alright, although I cannot use this in my special case this is still a good and valid answer. Hope it helps some people

Answer (score 1):

You can expose classes that you need from underlying `CoreFramework` in `MyFramework`

```
public typealias CoreStruct = CoreFramework.CoreStruct
```

Comment: I get `error: type alias cannot be declared public because its underlying type uses an internal type` when using this approach

Answer (score 0):

There is another way now to do it (in case anyone is still looking for this).
You can do an exported import in MyFramework:

```
import Foundation 
...
@_exported import CoreFramework

public struct MyFrameworkType {
...
}
```

A more thorough explanation can be found here: https://davedelong.com/blog/2018/01/19/simplifying-swift-framework-development/

Answer (score -2):

You could do

```
import struct CoreFramework.CoreStruct
```

to only import this particular type, see [The Swift Programming Language Reference: Import Declarations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/import-declaration).

Comment: But that means I still have to import it. I wanted to avoid any import to `CoreFramework` in the first place

Comment: As you see it the “accepted answer” there is no way to do so, the next best thing is to avoid importing the whole framework, possibly polluting your namespace.