# Undefined symbols issue with GoogleMobileAds

Tags: ios, swift, admob, arm64

I am building dynamic framework in which i am importing GoogleMobileAds framework (i am not linking it as binary)

I am simply importing it in the class code while keeping the framework on the project path without linking it in the "Link binary" in the build phases

```
import GoogleMobileAds
```

I am getting this error when trying to build the project:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADInterstitial", referenced from:
  static VeediSDK_admob.VeediUtils.loadNewAdd (VeediSDK_admob.VeediUtils.Type)() -> __ObjC.GADInterstitial in           
 VeediUtils.o
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADRequest", referenced from:
  static VeediSDK_admob.VeediUtils.loadNewAdd (VeediSDK_admob.VeediUtils.Type)() -> __ObjC.GADInterstitial in VeediUtils.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
```

Since i am building framework i don't want to link the GoogleMobileAds directly to the framework.

I made sure i am linking all the system frameworks required by GoogleMobileAds and confident that this is not the issue

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: similar error here: see if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213782/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64

Comment: add other linker flag in build setting -Objc

Answer (score 3):

i had same issue
in my case i removed pod and import adMob FrameWork manually from
https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/download
and just drag "GoogleMobileAds.framework" into my project,
clean and run

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. For me helped removing package External Dependency Manager from

> Assets/ExternalDependencyManager

Answer (score 0):

as Sultan Ali mentioned, I removed Google ads from my pods,  then I downloaded the Framework and added the folder to frameworks on the left side of xcode, but still didn't work, so I went to Targets->general->frameworks and I added GogleMobileAds.xcframework

Answer (score 0):

Just add these two values in Build Settings ->Other Linker Flags
$(inherited)
-ObjC
[see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lI4OH.png)