# How to build a Cocoa touch framework in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, frameworks

I want to build a Cocoa touch framework in iOS. My framework named as 'MyFramework' which depends on third party frameworks like 'GoogleWebRTC'.

I tried adding this through cocoa pods and also with drag into MyFramework project. But the issue is when I import MyFramework into any other Project, it gives error:

> Module 'WebRTC' not found

I have also seen that Apple discourage umbrella frameworks:

[Why are umbrella frameworks discouraged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365578/why-are-umbrella-frameworks-discouraged)

Then:

I want to understand how I can include this GoogleWebRTC.framework or any other third party lib. in MyFramework project and distribute to others.

Help is Appreciated!

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: @OgulcanOrhan solution for me was I have  to explicitly add GoogleWebRTC in the app with my framework. And if your framework can install by pods then you can mention your dependent third parties lib. in podspec file. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for me was that I have to explicitly add GoogleWebRTC in the app with my framework.

And if your framework can install by pods then you can mention your dependent third parties lib. in podspec file as below:

```
s.ios.dependency 'dependent framework pod'
```