# Class is implemented in both, One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined. (not cocoapods problem)

Tags: objective-c, frameworks

I'm implementing an umbrella framework but both of the frameworks (I have the code of both and they are as a reference in my xcode umbrela project) that I'm using uses the same local libraries (I'm not using `cocoapods` or any other dependency manager). This is causing the "Class is implemented in both. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined."...

How can I solve this?

All the questions about this same problem are about `cocoapods` problems. I tried to adapt the solution but the problem's cause is different.

Comment: iOS does not support user-land (non-Apple) umbrella frameworks, and they are strongly discouraged on macOS. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365578/why-are-umbrella-frameworks-discouraged

Comment: Marked as dupe;  long and short of it, you'll have to eliminate one copy of the class somehow.